# Mapping multiple test classes to the same file for autotest

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, autotest

I'm using [standalone autotest](http://rubygems.org/gems/autotest-standalone) in my projects along with [minitest](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest). In one of my projects, I have a single file (`validation.rb`) that validates a document to different internal format levels. (A Level 2 document has more features than a Level 1 document.)

Testing the validation for a particular level requires repeatedly loading in a known-valid document, subtly mutating it in broken way, and then ensuring that it is broken. In short:

```
class TestValidation < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    @l1 = Document.load( L1DOC )
  end
  def test_valid
    assert @l1.valid_level_1?
  end
  def test_unbalanced_data
    @l1.instance_eval{ @tracks[0].data.pop }
    refute @l1.valid_level_1?, "Validation must ensure that all tracks have the same amount of data"
  end
  # many more tests for level 1 here
end
```

The problem is that autotest (as far as I can tell) knows which tests to run based on the name of the test classes. `TestValidation` will have its tests automatically run when `validation.rb` is changed.

Without autotest, I would have named the above class `TestL1Validation`, and created a new class `TestL2Validation` that loaded a different document. Doing this breaks autotest, however, unless I break out my validation into `l1validation.rb` and `l2validation.rb`.

**How can I name my files or tests, or set up my tests, so that autotest will run multiple test classes when a single source file changes?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom mappings for autotest. Here's one way of doing it:
Create autotest directory at the same level as lib and test directories.

Add autotest/discover.rb:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.expand_path('../', File.dirname(__FILE__))
Autotest.add_discovery { "my_rules" }
```

Add autotest/my_rules.rb:

```
require 'autotest'

class Autotest::My_rules < Autotest
  def initialize
    super

    add_mapping(%r%^lib/valid.rb$%, true) { |filename, _|
      files_matching %r%^test/test_.*\.rb$%
    }
  end
end
```

This will add a custom mapping: whenever lib/valid.rb files has changed, re-run all test_*.rb files in test directory.